# Mongodb aggregate works slowly with 200Gb collection

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a sharded mongo collection with 10M elements (200Gb).

Document structure:

```
{
  _id
  updateDate
  cleanDate
  events1: [{...}, {...}, ...]
  events2: [{...}, {...}, ...]
  events3: [{...}, {...}, ...]
}
```

There is no indexes except `_id`.

1st java application creates, reads and updates documents from collection.

2nd java application has scheduled task that finds documents with `updateDate > cleanDate` and removes old objects from `eventX` arrays. When the task cleans any object, it updates `cleanDate`.

I use `myCollection.aggregate({ $project : { delta : { $cmp : ['$updateDate', '$cleanDate'] } } }, { $match : { delta : { $gt : 0 } } } , { $limit : 10000})` query to get next portion for cleaning.

The query execution takes a lot of time (sometimes 10 min and more) especially when the first elements was cleaned in collection.

How I can speed up my 2nd app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that whole your collection projects and $match only after that. If you know last `updateDate` or `cleanDate` (maybe you store last scheduled task run time somewhere) so you can limit initial aggregation set by this field prior projecting.